# Turn off login notification email for Facebook chat on a Mac

Tags: messages, notifications, facebook, chat

I have setup Facebook chat in *Messages* on my Mac. The problem is that every time *Messages* logs in to chat, I receive an email saying:

> It looks like someone logged into "Facebook Chat" on Sunday, March 2,
>   2014 at 11:07am. If this was you, please disregard this email. If this
>   wasn't you, please secure your account, as someone else may be
>   accessing it.

I understand that this is essentially a Facebook security mechanism to warn users about unauthorised access to their account. My question is: Is there a way to mark *Messages* as an 'authorised application' so that I don't get this notification email every time?

Comment: are you logging in from different locations (IP)

Comment: No. It's always from the same computer... same place.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Facebook

Settings-Security and disable the notifications there

[image]

Comment: This will turn off all login notifications. I still want notifications for any fraudulent login. I just don't want it for Facebook chat.